# get number from cell in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I use `hours.loc[numb]` to get cell in column
if I print this He prints it but like that:
[print:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCARQ.png)

how can me get Hours number only Without the rest of the printed stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
hours.loc[numb].values
```